# json array iteration and make own array list from the json array

Tags: javascript, json

Look the json array and then...

```
[
  {
    "country" : "Bangladesh",
    "deathInLastWeek" : [40, 42, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65],
    "maxDeath" : 82,
    "minDeath" : 5
  },
  {
    "country" : "India",
    "deathInLastWeek" : [100, 110, 95, 102, 89, 120, 98],
    "maxDeath" : 148,
    "minDeath" : 19
  },
  {
    "country" : "England",
    "deathInLastWeek" : [56, 62, 120, 56, 98, 91, 87],
    "maxDeath" : 124,
    "minDeath" : 13
  }
]
```

above json array iterate all fields and render those fields in a list.
and then set Two array like given below as a output.

```
 const dataMin = [
  { name: "Bangladesh", value: 5 },
  { name: "India", value: 19 },
  { name: "England", value: 13 }
];

 const dataMax = [
  { name: "Bangladesh", value: 82 },
  { name: "India", value: 148 },
  { name: "England", value: 124 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = [
  {
    country: "Bangladesh",
    deathInLastWeek: [40, 42, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65],
    maxDeath: 82,
    minDeath: 5,
  },
  {
    country: "India",
    deathInLastWeek: [100, 110, 95, 102, 89, 120, 98],
    maxDeath: 148,
    minDeath: 19,
  },
  {
    country: "England",
    deathInLastWeek: [56, 62, 120, 56, 98, 91, 87],
    maxDeath: 124,
    minDeath: 13,
  },
];

const [dataMin, dataMax] = array.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    const { country, maxDeath, minDeath } = curr;
    const minObj = { name: country, value: minDeath };
    const maxObj = { name: country, value: maxDeath };
    acc[0].push(minObj);
    acc[1].push(maxObj);
    return acc;
  },
  [[], []]
);

console.log(dataMin);
console.log(dataMax);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ittertare the array and make two separate arrays , something like this

```
let yourInitialArray = [
  {
    "country" : "Bangladesh",
    "deathInLastWeek" : [40, 42, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65],
    "maxDeath" : 82,
    "minDeath" : 5
  },
  {
    "country" : "India",
    "deathInLastWeek" : [100, 110, 95, 102, 89, 120, 98],
    "maxDeath" : 148,
    "minDeath" : 19
  },
  {
    "country" : "England",
    "deathInLastWeek" : [56, 62, 120, 56, 98, 91, 87],
    "maxDeath" : 124,
    "minDeath" : 13
  }
]
``

``
let dataMin = yourInitialArray.map((item) => {
   return {name : item.country , value : item.minDeath}})

let dataMax = yourInitialArray.map((item) => {
   return {name : item.country , value : item.maxDeath}})

``
console your dataMin and dataMax you can get the desired output
```

Comment: Anytime @captain rider

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using reduce

```
 const dataMin = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({ name: item.country, value: item.minDeath });
  return acc;
}, []);

const dataMax = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({ name: item.country, value: item.maxDeath });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Why to loop over data  array twice when you can do it in one loop